# How to report a potential rep-farming sock-puppet?

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets

I've just found a pair of users, one who only asks questions, one who only answers.

Both are low rep new users, and almost all the askers questions have accepted answers by the answerer. The answers aren't that good either.

- Asker: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693778/bert-castello1
- Answerer: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693838/web-dev-80

Comment: [Flag either the question or the answer for moderator attention.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DFS3I.png) They have the tools to handle sock puppets.

Comment: @Antony Flag every answer?

Comment: Just one of them. Put the profile links in the flag description, and mention that they are potential sock puppets. I have done it this way a few times before, and they will handle that in a few days.

Comment: Also, don't be surprised if nothing happens *right away*. I'm not commenting on these accounts, but I'll say that we try to be careful, and we sometimes put off an immediate action. But the above is what you should do.

Comment: Oh also; in *this* particular case, you've sort of already 'flagged' them, so to speak, by this post. (Still do a real flag, though)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Now I know for future reference.

Comment: They (he/she) don't appear to be very successful. 14 rep each only.

Comment: @Szymon Some... stuff... happened ;)